# What values does the algorithm parametre take in OpenCV's FlannBasedMatcher constructor?

Tags: python, opencv, flann

In python, OpenCV's `FlannBasedMatcher` constructor takes a dictionary of parametres, the first of which is `algorithm`. [The python tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html) suggests that one can specify different values of `algorithm` by passing differently named variables, e.g. `FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE` and `FLANN_INDEX_LSH`, but the variable *name* cannot, of course, convey anything to the constructor. One might think that these names should instead be passed as strings, but in the example that follows, `FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE` is initialised as 0, and so it is entirely unclear how the `algorithm` parametre works.

OpenCV doesn't really have any python documentation. [In C++](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html), the constructor doesn't take a generic dictionary, but an object that instantiates `IndexClass`, where each subclass of `IndexClass` corresponds to a different algorithm.

Answer (score 11):

`algorithm` takes an integer, what is missing from the tutorial is the initialisation of `FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE` and `FLANN_INDEX_LSH` with different values. (The upper case should have been a hint that these are meant as descriptive labels of fixed integer values.)

The [C++ source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/383559c2285baaf3df8cf0088072d104451a30ce/modules/flann/include/opencv2/flann/defines.h#L68) has such a list of initialisations, from which it appears that the LSH algorithm corresponds to the value 6. It also initialises `FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE` as 1, which means that either the python tutorial, which has 0, is wrong, or that the source code uses conflicting definitions in different places (that I missed), which would be unfortunate.

These are all the values in the source code:

```
FLANN_INDEX_LINEAR = 0
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
FLANN_INDEX_KMEANS = 2
FLANN_INDEX_COMPOSITE = 3
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE_SINGLE = 4
FLANN_INDEX_HIERARCHICAL = 5
FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
FLANN_INDEX_SAVED = 254
FLANN_INDEX_AUTOTUNED = 255
```

EDIT: I filed [a pull request](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/8245) fixing both issues that has now been accepted.