# Getting weird mesh while trying 3d reconstruction

Tags: python, opencv, 3d-reconstruction

I am trying to implement 3d reconstruction using opencv however the triangulation result is very weird. I am not able to understand where I am going wrong with this.[image][image]

Here is my code.

ThreeDReconstruct.py

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

class ThreeDReconstruct:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.matches_all=[]
        self.keypoints_and_descriptors=[]
        self.calib_images=[]
    
    def featureDetection(self):
        images=self.calib_images
        for i in tqdm(range(len(images)),desc="Features and Descriptors"):
            img=images[i]
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
            keypoints = sift.detect(gray, None)
            keypoints = sorted(keypoints, key=lambda x: -x.response)[:1000]
            keypoints, descriptors = sift.compute(gray, keypoints)
            self.keypoints_and_descriptors.append([keypoints,descriptors])
            
        # Matching
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397009/what-values-does-the-algorithm-parametre-take-in-opencvs-flannbasedmatcher-cons
        FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
        index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=4)
        search_params = dict(checks=2)
        flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

        for i in tqdm(range(len(self.keypoints_and_descriptors) - 1),desc="Matching"):
            matches = flann.knnMatch(self.keypoints_and_descriptors[i][-1], self.keypoints_and_descriptors[i + 1][-1], k=2)

            # Apply ratio test as per Lowe's paper
            # https://blog.finxter.com/5-effective-ways-to-implement-flann-based-feature-matching-in-opencv-python/
            goodMatches = []
            for (m, n) in matches:
                if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
                    goodMatches.append(matches)
            self.matches_all.append(goodMatches)
            
    def calibrateCamera(self,images):
         # termination criteria
        criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
        # prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
        objp = np.zeros((6*9,3), np.float32)
        objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:6,0:9].T.reshape(-1,2)
        # Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
        objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
        imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.
        for i in tqdm(range(len(images)),desc="Camera Calibration"):
            img = images[i]
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            # Find the chess board corners
            ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (6,9), flags=cv2.CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS)
            # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
            
            if ret == True:
                objpoints.append(objp)
                corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
                imgpoints.append(corners2)
                self.calib_images.append(img)
                
        ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
        return ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs 
        
    def save_ply_file(self,filename, vertices):
        header = """ply
        format ascii 1.0
        element vertex {}
        property float x
        property float y
        property float z
        end_header
        """.format(len(vertices))

        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(header)
            for vertex in vertices:
                f.write('{} {} {}\n'.format(vertex[0], vertex[1], vertex[2]))
```

example_usage.py

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ThreeDReconstruct import ThreeDReconstruct
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
import open3d as o3d

directory = "../images/"

image_files = sorted(glob.glob(directory + "*.jpg"))
images=[]
for image_file in image_files:
    image = cv2.imread(image_file)
    if image is not None:
        images.append(image)
    else:
        print(f"Unable to read image file: {image_file}")
    
    if len(images)>50:
        break

reconstrucClass = ThreeDReconstruct()

x_coords=[]
y_coords=[]
z_coords=[]

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs=reconstrucClass.calibrateCamera(images)
reconstrucClass.featureDetection()


for i in tqdm(range(len(reconstrucClass.keypoints_and_descriptors)-1),desc="Triangulation"):
    
    P1 = np.hstack((cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs[i])[0], tvecs[i]))
    P2 = np.hstack((cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs[i+1])[0], tvecs[i+1]))

    src_pts = np.float32(reconstrucClass.keypoints_and_descriptors[i][-1]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32(reconstrucClass.keypoints_and_descriptors[i+1][-1]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    

    points_4d=cv2.triangulatePoints(P1,P2,src_pts,dst_pts)
    # Convert homogeneous coordinates to 3D coordinates
    points_3d=cv2.convertPointsFromHomogeneous(points_4d.T)
    x_coords.extend(points_3d[:, 0, 0])
    y_coords.extend(points_3d[:, 0, 1])
    z_coords.extend(points_3d[:, 0, 2])
    

print(len(x_coords),len(y_coords),len(z_coords))
# Create 3D plot

reconstrucClass.save_ply_file("wine.ply",list(zip(x_coords,y_coords,z_coords)))

# Create a point cloud
point_cloud = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
point_cloud.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(zip(x_coords, y_coords, z_coords))

# Create a mesh from the point cloud
mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_alpha_shape(
    point_cloud, alpha=1.0
)

# Compute normals
mesh.compute_vertex_normals()

Save the mesh as an STL file
o3d.io.write_triangle_mesh("output_mesh.stl", mesh)
```

Here is an example of input image

[image]

I tried implementing the functions but I am surely doing something wrong. I have used chess board image for camera calibration in each image to ensure i get correct matrix for each image.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).